# Put aside unneeded tabs in firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Often I find that I have too many tabs opened and want to put some of them aside in one dropdown or something to clear out the space, so that I can concentrate while working.

For example while I am working on a web app I just want to show only couple of tabs and hide the rest in the corner.

What can I use to achieve this?

Comment: You could open a new window, then drag the tabs you want to concentrate on to that new window.

Comment: Firefox has building tab-groups, see Mokubai's answer. hotkey us ctrl+shift+E (or cmd+shift+E).

Answer (score 1):

yes there are some extension available which help in tab management check below URL

http://ohotech.com/2014/02/shows-tabs-vertically-in-google-chrome-and-mozilla-firefox.html

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/  - tree style addon

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use an addon then one feature that one feature that sounds like what you are after and is built in to Firefox is [Tab Groups](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tab-groups-organize-tabs).

With tab groups you can simply segment your workspace into nice neat little packages.

To get to the Tab Group either click the tab group button or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

[image]

Once there you can simply drag and drop tabs into groups, you drag one tab into empty space to create a new group.

[image]

In order to switch between tab groups simply press the button again and select the next group you want to use.  It's also easy to move tabs between groups.

If you want certain tabs to appear in all groups then you can use a [Pinned Tab](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pinned-tabs-keep-favorite-websites-open?esab=a&s=app%20tab&r=1&as=s).

Comment: I'm using this for a while now, a golden feature IMO. All tabs in the others groups don't load, you can name them, create manageble group, just perfect.